# Controller Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to insert values to db.

my model is

```
public bool Create(string userName) {
        _userNA = userName;
        if (validate()) {
            using (DatabaseCommaned cmd = new DatabaseCommaned()) {
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tUser(UNA, FNAID, MNAID, LNAID, Email, MobCountryCode, Mobile, ST, LN, ExpDT) VALUES(@una, @fnaid, @mnaid, @lnaid, @email, @mobCode, @mobile, @st, @ln, @exp)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@una", userName);
                ....


                _userID = cmd.ExecuteInsertAndGetID();
                if (_userID > 0) {
                    copyPropertiesInternally();
                    Logs.LogEvent(LogEvent.UserCreated, userName);
                    ResetPassword();
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    _userNA = string.Empty;
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        else 
            return false;
    }
```

can anybody tell how the controller is writing for the above model

Comment: Your naming convention sucks..

Comment: @BhushanFirake sorry. can u tell which values i pass from controller

Comment: Its very unclear what you are asking..

Comment: i want a controller action for this model.i write as follows.but not working [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(string username)
        {
            bool created = new User().Create(username);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

Comment: This is not "model" in either ASP.Net MVC meaning nor pure MVC. It is a method with one parameter. It is not clear what exactly the problem is - how to convert the method into something that resembles model or how to call method with one argument or something else.

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Does your controller action get called with expected data? Does the Create method on your User model get called? If not what errors are you seeing?

Comment: From comments it looks like your question is "why this piece of code fails (returns `false`). It is not possible to answer without debugging/knowing all about your system, and even if it would be possible it is way too localized for SO. Feel free to update your question to make my statement false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you're asking, but i'll take a punt at it:

```
public ActionResult Create(string UserName)
{
    var model = new User();
    var created = model.Create(UserName);
    if(created)
       return View();
    else
       return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**Edited in response to comments**:

You say you have a model. It should look something like this:

```
public class UserModel
{
   public string UserName {get;set}
   public string Email {get;set}
   public string FirstName {get;set}
}
```

Your controller action then should be:

```
public ActionResult Create(UserModel model)
{
    if (validate(model) {
         var user = new User();
         user.Create(model);
         return View();
    }
    else
       return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Your DB insert code should be:

```
public void Create(UserModel model) {
        _userNA = model.UserName;
        using (DatabaseCommaned cmd = new DatabaseCommaned()) {
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tUser(UNA, FNAID, MNAID, LNAID, Email, MobCountryCode, Mobile, ST, LN, ExpDT) VALUES(@una, @fnaid, @mnaid, @lnaid, @email, @mobCode, @mobile, @st, @ln, @exp)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@una", userName);
        //....


        _userID = cmd.ExecuteInsertAndGetID();
        if (_userID > 0) {
              copyPropertiesInternally();
              Logs.LogEvent(LogEvent.UserCreated, userName);
              ResetPassword();
              return true;
        }
        else {
              _userNA = string.Empty;
              return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This is a guideline only from the broken bits of info you've given. It'll hopefully put you on the right path.

Comment: sorry .This is not working.it is redirect to index page.not insert in db

Comment: That means your database insert is wrong, not the controller action. What's the exception error message you're getting? What does your validate() method do?

Comment: bool validate() {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName);
        }

Comment: are you passing in Email and FirstName?

Comment: i want ti insert all these in to db.but pass only username.others are in model

Comment: update my answer. hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Create a ViewModel class e.g. CreateUserViewModel

```
public class CreateUserViewModel
{
   //add properties reflecting the fields you want to capture in your HTML form

   [Required]
   public string UserName { get; set; }

   //... etc
}
```

Then create your controller

```
public ActionResult CreateUser(CreateUserViewModel model)
{
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      string username = model.UserName;
      //... etc

      bool created = MyUserModelClass.Create(username, ...);
      if(created)
          Return RedirectToAction("Index");
      else
          return View(model); //return the form
   }
   else
   {
      return View(model); //return the form
   }
}
```

Comment: sorry i got created is false